# ASP.Net website won't publish to IIS when targeted at x64 processors

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, 64-bit

Working on a large project with a number of interdependent DLL's, all of which were originally set to build for "Any CPU". We discovered that it was critical for one of them to run in x64 so, to avoid any possible issues we just set that project to build in x64.

Now the web project, which references that project, is refusing to publish. The error is the classic "could not load file or assembly" for the 64-bit DLL.

I have checked IIS and the App Pool for the site it's publishing to has Enable 32-Bit Applications set to False. Doing a manual publish of the compiled DLL's leads to the same error appearing when you run the site.

What else might be preventing IIS from accepting a specifically 64-bit DLL?

Comment: Is the 64-bit DLL referencing any DLLs compiled for x86?

Comment: @bnem It shouldn't be, although I haven't checked - but wouldn't that make the build fail? It builds fine: it just won't publish to IIS.

Comment: In my experience, unless you configure Visual Studio to report errors in this case, no. The compiler will just generate a warning. One of the DLLs being referenced, or a reference of a referenced DLL is most likely x86 only.

Comment: @bnem Well, that's useful info - much appreciated. However it doesn't appear to be the problem here: I've checked all the referenced dll's with corflags and they're all built to "Any CPU"

Comment: Then I would next check event viewer